# Forgot Password with LDAP in Meteor

Tags: meteor, ldap

I want to implement a ForgotPassword-Mail with Meteor 0.9.3. But after adding `accounts-password` forgotPassword runs, but LogIn doesn't run anymore. 
Although I've added `accounts-ui` before that, which runs well with my logIn. And when I try to submit my ForgotPassword with `accounts-ui`, the console throws: `Exception in delivering result of invoking 'returnEMail': ["submit #box-reset"]` 
I use exactly the same LogIn as on:
[LoginHandler with ldapjs and Meteor.methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996067/loginhandler-with-ldapjs-and-meteor-methods)

Code on the client side for forgotPassword:

```
Template.forgotPassword.events({
    'submit #box-reset': function(e,t){
        e.preventDefault();

        var forgotPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            username = trimInput(forgotPasswordForm.find('#forgotPasswordEmail').val().toLowerCase());

        if (isNotEmpty(username)){
            Meteor.call('returnEMail', username, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        Accounts.forgotPassword({ email: result}, function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
                                        Session.set('alert', 'This email does not exist.');
                                    } else {
                                        console.log(err);
                                        Session.set('alert', 'We\'re sorry but something went wrong.');
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Session.set('alert', 'Email Sent. Please check your mailbox to reset your password.');
                                }

                            });
                        }
                });
        } else{
            Session.set('alert','Please insert your username!')
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Code on the server Side:

```
verifyEmail = function(username) {
    LDAP.client = ldap2.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://' + LDAP.serverIP + ':' + LDAP.serverPort
    });

    future = new Future;

    LDAP.client.search(LDAP.searchOu, LDAP.searchQuery(username), function (err, req, res) {
        req.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
            LDAP.Mail = entry.object.mail;
        });

        req.on('error', function (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, "LDAP server error");
        });

        req.on('end', function(res, entry){
            future['return'](LDAP.Mail);
        });
    });
    return future.wait();
};

Meteor.methods({
    returnEMail: function(username, err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            return verifyEmail(username);
        };
    }
});
```

So is there any possiblity to still use `Accounts.forgotPassword`, which is really helpfull, or shall I fully refuse it? Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found it out: My former solution will not run and I still don't know y.

But I want to recommend u following pages, with which I solved my problem: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/315, [Email.send issue is email is not defined in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200268/email-send-issue-is-email-is-not-defined-in-meteor)

I still had to fit them to mine, but the basic is the same. ;)